# GPU Compare (AMD R9 390x and AMD R9 FURY X)

Tags: memory, graphics-card

I've come upon some graphics cards and could not figure out some of the details I found about them. I have some basic understanding but appear to be lacking in this specific area.

I've come to a point where I want to buy a new graphics card for my system.
And can't seem to figure out what to choose.

In general, the AMD R9 FURY X seems to get higher numbers in most specifications. However it has significantly lower numbers in the following areas:

- Memory Clock Speed (vs AMD R9 390X): 500MHz (vs 1500MHz)
- Effective Memory Clock Speed: 1000MHz (vs 6000MHz)
- Memory Amount

This webpage shows a more in-depth comparison between the two cards:
http://gpuboss.com/gpus/Radeon-R9-390X-vs-Radeon-FURY-X

**My questions are mainly the following:**

- How can I determine which card is better for gaming purposes?
- What are the deciding factors?
- Why does the FURY X card perform better (or so I read) with lower clock speeds?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The simpliest way to determine if you watch benchmarks or comparsions on youtube. Usually you can see the two cards performance on a splitted screen with the same pc. Type in the search xy vs xy and see if there any video. :)

Answer (score 0):

The R9 Fury X, will more than likely outperform the 390x. According the the PassMark benchmark page, the 390x scored 5,992, and the Fury X scored 8,191. That is a significant jump, but there is also a decent price difference between the two cards.

It's hard telling how the Fury X performs better with a lower clock speed, but it's all about the efficiency of the architecture. If you're going to be gaming in 1080P, I'd say the 390x will suit you just fine. If you're willing to spend a bit more money, then you can go ahead and get the Fury X.

I myself have a GTX 680 with 2 GB of VRAM and I still run all games on the highest settings, no problem. Both cards will suit your gaming needs with no problem. The deciding factor is knowing how much you want to spend.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to why the slower memory doesn't seem to be hurting the Fury X much, well, you're ignoring half of the story. You've got clock speed, but not bus width. The Fury X uses [High Bandwidth Memory (HBM)](http://www.anandtech.com/show/9266/amd-hbm-deep-dive) whereas the 390x uses the older GDDR5 standard for its memory.

HBM enables the Fury X to have a 4096-bit memory bus, compared to the 512-bit memory bus the 390x has.

So, while the 390x can make about 6 cycles (6000MHz/1000MHz) between graphics memory and GPU in the time it takes the Fury X to make one, the 390x needs to make 8 cycles (4096bits/512bits) to move the same amount of data as one cycle on the Fury X. Since 6 < 8, the Fury X actually has a greater memory bandwidth.